# Un-hiding css element to choose an element value is too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using the following method to un-hide css element to choose an element value:

```
val element = driver.find_element_by_id("company_stage")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class');", element)
```

and from some reason it takes like 15-20 sec for the program to remove it...how can I do it faster?
the time it takes dosent make sense

thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide the link to an actual website you are dealing with, or make the problem reproducible in a different way? Thanks.

Comment: How are you measuring those times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just on a Website you can use simple javascipt:

```
document.getElementById("company_stage").classList.remove("theclassnamewhichhidestheelement");
```

EDIT:

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) 
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('company_stage').classList.remove('theclassnamewhichhidestheelement');");
} 
else 
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
}
```

Comment: what is "document"? if you could please edit this code to be working with the elements I posted in the question it will be awesome

Comment: I don't really know selenium but as i guess you just have to execute the code I gave you above without any elements.. Are you using a css stylesheet for hiding the element?

Comment: I didnt build the website, and im only doing the automation, there was some elements that was hided so I removed them like this. I use scala in my automation proj

Comment: Now you just have to replace theclassnamewhichhidestheelement with the actual css class which hides the element